# Mockito doNothing not Working - Mock created and Injected but file still being created and not skipping method

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, junit5

Using `com.spire` library to convert `.docx` to `.pdf`.

I am trying to test the catch block of a method that converts word docs to pdfs. I have verified the method works correctly and implemented a test to check the method.

The issue I have is, when trying to test the catch block, I want the `.saveToFile()` method to `doNothing()`. Unfortunately, when I utilise `Mockito.doNothing()` the file I want it to not create, still gets created, so the `doNothing()` is still doing something.

Here is my test class:

```java
public class PDFConverterTest {
    PDFConverter converter;
    String outPdf = "src/test/resources/outputTest.pdf";
    String inDoc = "src/test/resources/inputTest.docx";
@Test
    void testPDFNotCreated() {
        Document doc = mock(Document.class);
        converter = new PDFConverter(inDoc, outPdf, doc);
        doNothing().when(doc).saveToFile(anyString());

        assertFalse(converter.convertWordToPDF());

        verify(doc).saveToFile(outPdf);
    }
}
```

The class under test:

```java
public class PDFConverter {
    private final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger();
    private final Path DOC_IN;
    private final Path PDF_OUT;
    private final Document DOC;

    public PDFConverter() throws IOException {
        super();
        DOC_IN = Paths.get("output.docx");
        PDF_OUT = Paths.get("output.pdf");
        DOC = new Document(Files.newInputStream(DOC_IN));
    }

    public PDFConverter(String inDoc, String outPDF, Document doc) {
        super();
        DOC_IN = Paths.get(inDoc);
        PDF_OUT = Paths.get(outPDF);
        DOC = doc;
    }

    public PDFConverter(String inDoc, String outPdf) {
        super();
        DOC_IN = Paths.get(inDoc);
        PDF_OUT = Paths.get(outPdf);
        DOC = new Document();
    }

    public boolean convertWordToPDF() {
        try {
            LOGGER.info("Converting to PDF...");
            DOC.saveToFile(Files.newOutputStream(PDF_OUT), FileFormat.PDF);
            LOGGER.info("Conversion complete.");
            if (Files.isRegularFile(PDF_OUT)) return true;
            else throw new IOException();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error(e);
            LOGGER.error("Conversion failed. Please check file paths are correct and not empty and input is .docx and output is .pdf format.");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I have used the debugger to verify my mock is being created and interacted with, the issue is I get an AssertionFailure:

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :false
Actual   :true
```

Because the file gets created when it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a different signature than you are mocking for. You are mocking the `saveToFile(String)` signature, not `saveToFile(OutputStream, FileFormat)`. You need to adjust your mock appropriately, then it should work fine.

```
@Test
void testPDFNotCreated() {
    Document doc = mock(Document.class);
    converter = new PDFConverter(inDoc, outPdf, doc);
    doNothing().when(doc).saveToFile(any(OutputStream.class), eq(FileFormat.PDF));

    assertFalse(converter.convertWordToPDF());

    verify(doc).saveToFile(outPdf);
}
```

Comment: Firstly, the Stream.class is not part of java.io so I can't use that. I tried using `any(OutputStream.class)` but that didn't work either. Thanks for pointing out the signature was wrong but even with what I have now it still doesn't work: `doNothing().when(doc).saveToFile(any(OutputStream.class), eq(FileFormat.PDF));`

Comment: Sorry, I had my wires crossed between Java and .Net classes. Updated answer, you should probably be able to use just `any()`.

Comment: the edit just gives me this error: `Ambiguous method call. Both
saveToFile
(String,
FileFormat)
in Document and
saveToFile
(OutputStream,
FileFormat)
in Document match`

Comment: My mistake, there is a `saveToFile(String, FileFormat)` and `saveToFile(OutputStream, FileFormat)` . And `any(OutputStream.class)` doesn't work? Can you verify the correct signature of the `saveToFile(...)` that you are calling? Is it `OutputStream` for the first parameter? Spire doesn't seem to have an API reference for Java, only .Net.

Comment: So right now, with the `doNothing()` setup like so: `doNothing().when(doc).saveToFile(any(OutputStream.class), eq(FileFormat.PDF));` it still fails. Here's the verify: `(doc).saveToFile(outPdf);`

The signature of `saveToFile` in use is definitely `(OutputStream, FileFormat)`:
`public void saveToFile(java.io.OutputStream stream, com.spire.doc.FileFormat fileFormat )`

Comment: That's odd, the `any(OutputStream.class)` parameter SHOULD work fine. I don't have Spire, but I wrote a simple `Foo` class with a `bar(String, String)` and `bar(OutputStream, String)` methods. When I mock it and do the same setup here, it works correctly for me.

Comment: That is weird... though I just noticed a different class I was using doNothing for a different method that makes a different file type, when I commented it out, the file still wasn't created, so I have a doNothing where a file gets created and method being called that doesn't create a file without a doNothing... I thought Mockito was meant to be simple... that or my design is flawed...